# How to set the viewport size using webdriverio version 5

Tags: javascript, viewport, webdriver-io

Using webdriverio v4 you were able to run

```
browser.setViewportSize(size);
```

However in version 5 there is no equivalent.  The closest option is

```
browser.setWindowSize(height, width);
```

which will result in different viewport sizes.  How do I set the exact viewport size in version 5?

Comment: Hi @matthew-frederick-duro-brown, I've the same question, did you find a solution for that ? Thanks

Comment: No I didn't find one.  I ended up looking into the source of how it used to be done and hacking a solution from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4421) the functionality has been dropped in the v5 release.

In case anyone is still struggling with this, I created a service that ports the functionality: https://github.com/mondata-dev/wdio-viewport-size

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the viewport size initially, this can be accomplished in Chrome using `goog:chromeOptions` in your capabilities, e.g.

```
capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
      }
    }
  ]
```